# Using session to store form input values in order to uso in another view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am storing some form values, which is a list filter, from a post method in the request.session in order to use it in another view function to render the filtered results. The problem is any user that I log in keep the results stored, if they access the results page directly they will see other users filter results.

I use pagination (digg without AJAX), I am using django-el-pagination.

the views.py

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ComprarBuscaForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cidade = form.cleaned_data['cidade']
            request.session['cidade'] = form.cleaned_data['cidade']
            request.session['quartos'] = form.cleaned_data['quartos']
            request.session['tipo_imovel'] = form.cleaned_data['tipo_imovel']
            request.session['preco_minimo'] = form.cleaned_data['preco_minimo']
            request.session['preco_maximo'] = form.cleaned_data['preco_maximo']
            request.session['area_minima'] = form.cleaned_data['area_minima']
            request.session['area_maxima'] = form.cleaned_data['area_maxima']
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('imoveis:resultado_busca'))

    else:
        form = ComprarBuscaForm()
    return render (request, 'imoveis/busca_comprar.html', {'form':form})

def search_result(request):
    anuncios = Anuncio.objects.filter(quartos=request.session['quartos'],
                                   cidade=request.session['cidade'],
                                   tipo_imovel=request.session['tipo_imovel'],
                                   preco_venda__gte=request.session['preco_minimo'],
                                   preco_venda__lte=request.session['preco_maximo'],
                                   area_construida__gte=request.session['area_minima'],
                                   area_construida__lte=request.session['area_maxima'],
                                   tipo_anuncio='Venda')
    return render(request, 'imoveis/resultado_busca_comprar.html', {'anuncios': anuncios})
```

Everything is working fine although the fact I mentioned before. I am wondering if what I am doing is the right approach for this kind of situation.

Comment: It's not clear what you're saying. Sessions are specific to a user, going to the search result page would only show the query results stored in that user's session.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, that is what I though when I wrote the code. But I don't understand why it is happening, this is the core of my question.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I did the tests again. My login system was merging the accounts with same e-mail, and my tests were using my username and my gmail account. The code is working. Now if I try to acess the result page an error accour because it doesn't find any request.session variable stored.

Answer (score 0):

Is it really necessary to use two views for this? I would filter and render in the same form view if I were you.

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ComprarBuscaForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            anuncios = Anuncio.objects.filter(quartos=request.session['quartos'],
                                   cidade=request.session['cidade'],
                                   tipo_imovel=form.cleaned_data['tipo_imovel'],
                                   preco_venda__gte=form.cleaned_data['preco_minimo'],
                                   preco_venda__lte=form.cleaned_data['preco_maximo'],
                                   area_construida__gte=form.cleaned_data['area_minima'],
                                   area_construida__lte=form.cleaned_data['area_maxima'],
                                   tipo_anuncio='Venda')
            return render(request, 'imoveis/resultado_busca_comprar.html', {'anuncios': anuncios})

    else:
        form = ComprarBuscaForm()
    return render (request, 'imoveis/busca_comprar.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: It is not possible to use pagination on this way.